# Flot pie chart edges cut off

Tags: flot

I have the following code showing a pie chart with Flot:

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: #000000">
    <div id="divChartContainer" style="width: 50px; height: 50px"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $.plot($('#divChartContainer'), [{data: 60, color: '#F0F0F0'},{data: 40, color: '#F68E22'}],  { 
        series: { 
            pie: { 
                show: true, 
                stroke: { width: 2, color: '#F0F0F0'},
                label:  { show: false },
                }, 
            legend: { show: false }
        }
    });
});
```

This is also in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pagq5Lbd/) here. I'm not sure why the top, bottom, left and right edges are being cut off as I've told the chart to be 50px high and wide.

Comment: The `stroke.width` option is causing the cut-off edges. Setting the `radius` to 49 makes the pie smaller, fixing the cut-off edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221375/flot-pie-chart-edges-cut-off#comment54247492_33221375) from mechenbier, you need to get the size of the pie smaller then the size of the container so that the stroke still stays inside the container. The easiest solution is setting the radius to 24 (it needs to be smaller then half the height/width of the container):

```
pie: { 
    show: true, 
    stroke: { width: 2, color: '#F0F0F0'},
    label:  { show: false },
    startAngle: 3/2,
    radius: 24
},
```

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pagq5Lbd/3/).